# Как улучшить защиту по структуре скрытия?

Tags: javascript, html

Скорее вопрос прозвучал не корректно, но я все объясню. Имеется два неких див блока в html коде, в одном из них располагается форма с авторизацией пользователя, если авторизация прошла успешно, то див блок с авторизация скрывается, и после появляется второй блок. Я прекрасно понимаю, что каждый кто зайдет на сайт, сможет нажать "исследовать элемент" и убрать у второго блока `display:none`, после чего пользователь не пройдя регистрацию будет иметь доступ к скрытой информации. Как поменять структуру или код дабы избежать этого?

Comment: Тривиально, данные для второго блока присылаются только после авторизации.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, подумал об этом, просто масштабы второго блока испугали.

Comment: @Kirzzz Вы можете просто второй блок поместить в отдельный html и подгружать его либо через `ajax`, либо просто через `jquery` `$('ClassKudaZagruzit').load('file.html');`

Comment: @Denis640Kb Я так и сделал в итоге)